# print (-)minus decimal value RightToLeft

Tags: c#

```
decimal abc = -123;
StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
drawFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft;

graphics.DrawString(abc.ToString(), new Font("Segoe UI", 10, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 100, 100, drawFormat);
```

It was return `123-`
but I want `-123`.

Comment: Use `stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far` to right-justify yout text instead of DirectionRightToLeft (which is for right-to-left alphabets like Hebrew)

Comment: thanks its working..